# Why these methods are not accessible from Show_Page() method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Why is it I am not able to access other methods outside Show_Page? Hers's my code below.

```
class Main:

    style = ttk.Style()
    style.map("C.TButton",
    foreground=[('pressed', 'red'), ('active', 'blue')],
    background=[('pressed', '!disabled', 'black'), ('active', 'white')]
    )

    def selectReports():
        messagebox.showinfo("EDP", "All reports")

    def showReports():
        messagebox.showinfo("EDP", "Select reports")


    def Show_Page():
        program = tk.Tk()
        program.geometry("626x431")
        monitor = ttk.Button(name="",text="Monitor",command=showReports,style="C.TButton")
        monitor.pack(pady=100)
        review = ttk.Button(name="",text="Review",command=selectReports,style="C.TButton")


        review.pack(pady=0)
        # program.withdraw()
        program.mainloop()
    
    # Main method 
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        Show_Page()
```

***This is the following error I am getting.
"showReports" is not definedPylancereportUndefinedVariable***

Comment: Please post the entire traceback message in a code block so we can see context.

Comment: its better to edit the question and post the traceback there. And treat it like a code sample (use the {} code block tool). Its hard to read in the comment.

Comment: Your code seems to be set up to create more than one instance of `Tk` which usually results in non-intuitive errors.

Comment: @BryanOakley 
How to change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showReports` is a method of the class, but When you write

```
monitor = ttk.Button(name="",text="Monitor",command=showReports,style="C.TButton")
```

python will look for a function in the global namespace, not a method on the object. If you wrote `self.showReports` python would find the method you want.

Except for another bug in your code. Python requires that an object's "self" reference be included in the method parameter list. This is because methods are just regular python functions with some special sauce added. So, also define your methods as in

```
    def Show_Page(self):
        program = tk.Tk()
        program.geometry("626x431")
        monitor = ttk.Button(name="",text="Monitor",command=self.showReports,style="C.TButton")
    monitor.pack(pady=100)
        review = ttk.Button(name="",text="Review",command=selectReports,style="C.TButton")
```